# List view assigned to roles can't be seen by users with that role

Tags: security, list-view, roles

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple here. We have a list view on case where visibility is extended to a set of roles:

[image]

**However, when I login as a user with one of the defined roles, the UI throws a security exception:**

[image]

I have verified that the user does in fact have the correct role:

[image]

Is this a system bug? Has anyone encountered this before? If I'm logged in as a system admin I can see the view as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did indeed end up being something simple - the view was filtered to records owned by a queue, which the user was not a member of. Setting the owner filter to "All Cases" resolved the issue.

[image]